# Keep an element centred between, or above, two other elements

Tags: css

I've managed to get CSS3 to *almost* do what I want:

1. The grey `.top-middle` container is of arbitrary width, and must always remain flush with the top edge of the parent container (the `<main>`).
2. The purple *left* and *right* containers are also of arbitrary width, and must always remain flush with their respective edges of the parent container.
3. When the parent container is sufficiently wide, the three top containers should sit side-by-side; otherwise, the *left* and *right* containers should sit just beneath the `.top-middle` container. (It would be nice if the two purple containers dropped at the same time, but I'll live with one of them remaining next to the middle container, when there's space.)
4. The minimum width of the `<main>` container should essentially be the width of the `.top-middle` container
5. **The `.top-middle` container should be centred, ideally relative to the parent container (`<main>`), but at least relative to the horizontal space available to it (between the *left* and *right* containers)**

It's that last requirement, #5, that I haven't managed.

I'd prefer not to resort to JavaScript, and of course, it needs to be a cross-browser solution. (I don't really care about IE < 11, though—people using that cruft have bigger worries than whether my CSS looks pretty!)

**N.B. This issue cannot (AFAIK) be tested in jsfiddle, StackOverflow's code snippet feature, or any other fixed-width environment. Please copy my code and paste it into a file, and watch what happens when you widen or narrow the browser window.**

Here's my complete code, for your copying and pasting pleasure:

```css
main div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}
.top-container {
  background: olive;
}
.top-middle {
  background: grey;
}
.top-left,
.top-right {
  background: purple;
}
.bottom-container {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The crux of the layout starts here */

main {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top-container>* {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
.top-left {
  float: left;
}
.top-right {
  float: right;
}
.spacer {
  background: silver;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="top-container">
    <div class="top-middle">
      This should be centred, and always stay on top.
      <em>Left</em> and <em>right</em> should drop when the window contracts.
    </div>
    <div class="top-left">left</div>
    <div class="top-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="bottom-container">This is the bottom.</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Could you put this into a jsfiddle it would be easier to debug

Comment: @MattStephens: I welcome you to do so (like Chris did below), but I'm not convinced you'll be able to test all the requirements—I'm not sure you can resize containers in JSFiddle. Editing a file and refreshing a page in a browser is pretty easy, anyhow.

Comment: Use a media query and define the style precisely for each size.

Comment: @wwwmarty: I think that would only work if the *left*, *right* and `.top-middle` containers were a known, fixed width. This is not true in my case. I've clarified this in the question.

Comment: I disagree.  You could use display:table properties for the nice flex-box behavior, and switch to display:block styles for the smaller breakpoint.

Comment: @wwwmarty: Thanks, but I don't understand what you're getting at. If you put some working code in an answer, I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear.  At the office and not able to send you a test code.  My point is simple enough: you have the styles you need for the difficult layout, and if you use a media query you can define a whole other set of styles for the smaller layout.  I think the trouble you're encountering is trying to find a single set of styles that can handle both layouts.  Split them apart and make your life easy :)

Comment: @wwwmarty: I'm not sure what you mean by 'both'. Browser windows, and content, can be any width... maybe Apple browsers only have a small number of set widths, but I'm looking for a cross-platform solution. Also, the width of the content in the left and right boxes depends on language, how large the user has their font size set, etc. I know some designers like to think all users and their platforms are the same, and try to shoehorn content to fixed sizes like that, but the results are pretty ugly in the real world.

Comment: Chris gave you an answer below, and you replied that it violates #3, to stack the divs below a certain width.  Define a media query for that width, and change the display properties to block instead of table-cell, so they stack when the browser is too narrow.

Comment: @MichaelScheper I've amended my answer, given the Firefox bug I can't think of a way this can be achieved without JavaScript.

Comment: @wwwmarty: Thank you, but that 'certain width' depends on the content of the containers, which are not constant—that's what I meant by 'arbitrary width'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fifth requirement can be achieved by making the following change:

- Add `text-align: center;` to `.top-container`

This works because `text-align` effects the alignment of `inline` elements:

> The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.

text-align (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

`.top-middle` is set to be `inline-block` due to `.top-container>* { display: inline-block; padding: 1em; }` so will be centered within `.top-container`.

```css
main div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}
.top-container {
  background: olive;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-middle {
  background: grey;
}
.top-left,
.top-right {
  background: purple;
}
.bottom-container {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The crux of the layout starts here */

main {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top-container>* {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
.top-left {
  float: left;
}
.top-right {
  float: right;
}
.spacer {
  background: silver;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="top-container">
    <div class="top-middle">
      This should be centred, and always stay on top.
      <em>Left</em> and <em>right</em> should drop when the window contracts.
    </div>
    <div class="top-left">left</div>
    <div class="top-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="bottom-container">This is the bottom.</div>
</main>
```

Unfortunately, there is a drawback with this method as a bug in Firefox will always force `.top-left` and `.top-right` onto a new line:

> Also affecting Bugzilla itself, as glob pointed out on IRC. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677757#c4 has the
>   "comment 4" text hidden
>
> The cause is this code in nsLineLayout::ReflowFrame:
>
> ```
>  if (psd->mNoWrap) {
>    // If we place floats after inline content where there's
>    // no break opportunity, we don't know how much additional
>    // width is required for the non-breaking content after the float,
>    // so we can't know whether the float plus that content will fit
>    // on the line. So for now, don't place floats after inline
>    // content where there's no break opportunity. This is incorrect
>    // but hopefully rare. Fixing it will require significant
>    // restructuring of line layout.
>    // We might as well allow zero-width floats to be placed, though.
>    availableWidth = 0;
>  }
> ```
>
> I wonder whether the right thing to do is:
> * not manipulate the
>   available width at all, or
> * make the available width infinite, since
>   the nowrap content is never going to wrap around the float anyway
>
> (In theory, the correct solution is not to try placing the float until
>   the following break opportunity.  I wonder if other browsers do that.)

Bug 488725 - float pushed down one line with white-space: nowrap; (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725)

You could also use `flex` to center `.top-middle` although this wont push both `.top-left` and `.top-right` down to a new line when the space is taken up. To achieve this make the following changes:

- Add `display: flex;` to `.top-container` to make its children use the flexbox model
- Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.top-container` to make its children wrap onto new lines when they run out of space
- Add `justify-content: space-between;` to `.top-container` to add space around the child elements which will center `.top-middle`

```css
main div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}
.top-container {
  background: olive;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.top-middle {
  background: grey;
}
.top-left,
.top-right {
  background: purple;
}
.bottom-container {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The crux of the layout starts here */

main {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top-container>* {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
.top-left {
  float: left;
}
.top-right {
  float: right;
}
.spacer {
  background: silver;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="top-container">
    <div class="top-left">left</div>
    <div class="top-middle">
      This should be centred, and always stay on top.
      <em>Left</em> and <em>right</em> should drop when the window contracts.
    </div>
    <div class="top-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="bottom-container">This is the bottom.</div>
</main>
```

To get both `.top-left` and `.top-right` moving onto a new line when they run out of space you will need to use JavaScript. The following is using vanilla JavaScript but should provide a good starting point. In principle:

- We check to see if the combined width of `.top-left`, `.top-middle` and `.top-right` is equal to or bigger than `.top-container`

  - **If it is** then we change the `order` of `.top-left` and `.top-right` to place them after `.top-middle`. We add `margin` to `.top-left` to force it onto a new line and `margin` to `.top-middle` to center it (as there are no elements in the same line for `justify-content: space-between;` to work)
  - **If it isn't** we set the styles back to the defaults

```js
var topContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('top-container')[0];
var topLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('top-left')[0];
var topMiddle = document.getElementsByClassName('top-middle')[0];
var topRight = document.getElementsByClassName('top-right')[0];
var topContainerWidth;
var topLeftWidth = topLeft.offsetWidth;
var topMiddleWidth = topMiddle.offsetWidth;
var topRightWidth = topRight.offsetWidth;
var moveDivs;
(moveDivs = function(){
  topContainerWidth = topContainer.offsetWidth;
  if ((topLeftWidth + topMiddleWidth + topRightWidth) >= topContainerWidth) {
    topLeft.style.order = 1;
    topLeft.style.marginRight = topRightWidth + 'px';
    topMiddle.style.margin = '0 auto';
    topRight.style.order = 2;
  } else {
    topLeft.style.order = 0;
    topLeft.style.marginRight = 0;
    topMiddle.style.margin = 0;
    topRight.style.order = 2;
  }
})();

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  moveDivs();
});
```

```css
main div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}
.top-container {
  background: olive;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.top-middle {
  background: grey;
}
.top-left,
.top-right {
  background: purple;
}
.bottom-container {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The crux of the layout starts here */

main {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top-container>* {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
.top-left {
  float: left;
}
.top-right {
  float: right;
}
.spacer {
  background: silver;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="top-container">
    <div class="top-left">left</div>
    <div class="top-middle">
      This should be centred, and always stay on top.
      <em>Left</em> and <em>right</em> should drop when the window contracts.
    </div>
    <div class="top-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="bottom-container">This is the bottom.</div>
</main>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because of the second sentence you quoted: 'text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content'. It may not be evident in the narrow window above, but it's the block itself that's not centred. Save your code to a file and see for yourself—I've tried it in three browsers.

Comment: @MichaelScheper If you make it full screen (click the "Full page" link at the top right) you will see it does work. It does so because you have set the `.top-middle` to `inline-block` making it `inline` content.

Comment: @MichaelScheper Saved the code, ran it locally and can confirm that it also works. If it isn't working for you (in either the Stack Snippet or locally) then there must be something in play on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the link. And I apologise—I somehow stuffed up copying your code to a file, before. This still doesn't quite do what I want, though—I want the top three containers to sit side-by-side (vertically aligned), when there's room.

Comment: @MichaelScheper No problem. Hmm, well, it should do that. Which browser are you testing in? **Edit:** I would take a guess at Firefox as I can see what you are referring to... Interesting. Chrome and IE display it as you require. Will try to find out why this is.

Comment: Could be a bug in Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725, the Fiddle posted by marek in the bug report shows similar behavior. Might have to rethink this approach in that case.

Comment: Hmmm... indeed, it works in Chrome. How frustrating that that bug's been open for 6 years! But it seems your CSS is correct, so you've earnt my upvote. Thanks!

Comment: This is an excellent answer—thanks for adding the comments about flexbox, etc. I did try these approaches myself before posting the question, but never managed to get the perfect combo... but I was indeed testing in FireFox. I'm making this the 'accepted answer' for now, since I think you're right that JavaScript is required to work around the Firefox bug.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelScheper. I would prefer not to use JavaScript for style  manipulations but I can't think of a way to get the desired result otherwise. There are a few different ways to align the boxes at the top with `.top-middle` in the middle, but pushing `.top-left` and `.top-right` down to the new line is the killer! It's a real shame about the Firefox bug.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged your markup and used `display: table-cell`. Here's the fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/k108vt58/. Hope this helps and is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but this violates requirement #3. When I contract the main container, the left and right elements don't drop down—the right one breaches the container. (I'm not sure it's possible to test this in JSFiddle, but when I copy your code to a file and test it in a browser, this becomes evident when I contract the browser window.)